# Textviews inside tabs

Tags: android

I have three tabs.
I'd like to know if a tab can have more than one textview.Everytime I try to add a new textview, even if in different positions on the screen, they appear overlapped.

The details would be alligned on the left and the data would be alligned on the right. I can't write the way I want in here because I don't how to put tabs.

But the idea is something like: on the left a perfect column with Name, Login, Address, etc... and on the right side a perfect column with the name, the login, the address, etc...

What I'd like to do is something like, for example:

## |Personal| -> tab

Inside the tab:

#### Information

Name:               Zoe Shnoeder

Login:              zoe-shnd

Address:            Ulisses Street, London, UK

Date of birth:      13/11/1990

#### Contacts

Telephone:         2134212

E-mail:            zoeshn@hotmail.com

And if possible a square around Information and its details and another square around Contacts and its details, like

-Contacts---------------------------

| Telephone:    2134212            |

### | E-mail:       zoeshn@hotmail.com |

Thanks in advance,
Rita

Comment: @ Rita U want add text views in Tab Bar?

Comment: you need to go through the android layout documents . whatever you have mention here everything is possible with modifying your layout and the square that you need you can either set a background image with square boarder or you can create a custom square boarder using shape feature of android follow this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: Hi. I can't just set a background image with a square border because the data size is variable and it might overlap the border then. Do you know if I can add more than one textview per tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some layout that will contain your `TextView`s. I'd suggest you to start [with this one](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html)
**Edit:**

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
TextView nameView = new TextView(this);
nameView.setText("text");
layout.addView(nameView);
TextView anotherView = new TextView(this);
anotherView.setText("anotherTextView");
layout.addView(anotherView);
setContentView(layout);
```

Consider to make your layout with textviews in xml, and DO refer to the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks but I need to format the data inside the textview. I want something like: Name (tab) the_name (new line) Login (tab) the_login, where the_name and the_login would be alligned. Any idea?

Comment: replace your textview with linear layout with textviews. 1 textview for login, 2nd for name and so on.

Comment: As I said before, the problem is that I can't create more than one textview since they get overlapped...

Comment: OK. How do you create these textviews so they overlaps each other? Post the code pls, I can't get you.

Comment: TextView tv = new TextView(this); tv.setText("Hello"); tv.setTextColor(Color.RED); setContentView(tv); tv.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM); Like that... even if I create another textview with Gravity.TOP, for example, it still overlaps...

Comment: It's only 1 textview... how do you overlap it with another?

Comment: I was just showing how I create... Another one is: TextView tx2 = new TextView(this); tx2.setText("Hi2"); setContentView(tx2); tx2.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);

Comment: THANK YOU!! that worked! I knew that the problem was the setcontentview but I had no idea how to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

hmm ... alright... here it is...

`TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);\\ the 
TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab
        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, YourClass1.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

and finally

`tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);` \ first tab starts with 0 and the second 1 and so on

Then in the Class just display a view with all the stings to be filled by default in the layout and use a relative layout which gives you a better control over the placement of the views. Please let me know if you have any other issues.

rajesh

Comment: Hi, I already have the tabs! The problem is that each tab only takes one textview and I want to format the text in it

Comment: Hi rita could you please send me the code in the class you are using pertaining to the setContent() method;

Comment: I guess your looks something like this... `setContentView(tdsw);` where tdsw is a textview only.....

Comment: TextView tv = new TextView(this); tv.setText("Hello"); tv.setTextColor(Color.RED); setContentView(tv); this works, but I want more than one textview... if I create another one, this one is overlapped!

Comment: haha... that is the problem as i told you... you need to define a layout in the xml file as main.xml or something.... yeah as the answer from the above post suggest.. the developer pages are a good palce to start...